# update a variable within a function?

Tags: validation, variables, python-3.x, user-input

I'm teaching myself python 3.x and am struggling to resolve an issue I'm having with variable scope.

In my program, I ask the user for an input, and then run a function to check its value. If the value is correct, I continue. Otherwise, I wish to allow the user to change their previous input and retest with the new value. The values I am looking for are the strings: '0', '1', '2',... '8', '9'.

The code below is incorrect, but its the best I've been able to come up with so far. The problem I see is that while I can change the variable user_input within the function check_input(), I do not know how to change the scope of the variable.

For example, if I run the program and type 'abc' for rating_A, I will get the 'too many characters' message, and will be asked to try again. I now enter '7', and all seems dandy. But when I call rating_A later, I will get 'abc', not the desired '7'.

I've tried to fix this with the global variable technique. My difficulty with that is that I wish to check a large amount of input values, and each will have its own variable (rating_A, rating_B.... rating_Y, rating_Z). I imagine there is a much more elegant way to accomplish this?

```
from string import digits

def check_input(user_input):

    while True:

        if len(user_input) != 1:
            print (user_input, 'has too many characters!')
            user_input = input('try again: ')
            continue

        elif user_input in digits:
            print (user_input, 'is valid!')
            user_input = int(user_input)
            return user_input
            break

        else:
            print (user_input, 'is not a valid input!')
            user_input = input('try again: ')
            continue


rating_A = input('Please enter a value for A: ')
check_input(rating_A)
print ()
rating_B = input('Please enter a value for B: ')
check_input(rating_B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you really, but in case it's valid, you are already returning user_input, thus

```
rating_A = input('Please enter a value for A: ')
rating_A = check_input(rating_A)
```

assigns the final return value to your variable and you are set.

Otherwise I apologize for not understanding your request well.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and apologies about the lack of clarity. What I am trying to figure out is if there is a way to change rating_A within the check_input function, without using global variables.

Comment: Whatever you have inside a function has scope of the function. If you need to have access outside it you need global scope. You may also think of classes if it suits your needs.